# Is transpiling optimizing fields away?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, webpack

I'm trying to just get a basic Knockout model working in TypeScript, but I think that when I'm transpiling through webpack, that it's optimizing away "unused" variables

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

export class ViewModel {
    public firstName: "James";
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

but the compiled version of ViewModel is

`var ViewModel = (function () {\r\n    function ViewModel() {\r\n    }`

so I'm getting an error when binding like so

`<p data-bind="text: firstName"></p>`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return firstName }"
Message: firstName is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class ViewModel {
    public firstName: "James";
}
```

A colon indicates a *type annotation*, so you're saying that the `firstName` field will have type `"James"` (a string literal type). As with all types in TypeScript, this gets erased at compile time.

I think what you're trying to do is set an initial value for the `firstName` field, so you should use `=` instead:

```
export class ViewModel {
    public firstName = "James";
}
```

Or with a type:

```
export class ViewModel {
    public firstName : string = "James";
}
```

Both compile to the expected output:

```
var ViewModel = (function () {
    function ViewModel() {
        this.firstName = "James";
    }
    return ViewModel;
}());
```